# "Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string"

Tags: bash, scripts, backup, syntax

I am trying to use a backup script that will backup my sql database and website files.
I am running Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit version and zPanel.

Also what are these variables:

MYSQL="$()"
MYSQLDUMP="$()"
GZIP="$()"

I assume the first one is DB name.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Daily Backup Routine - Backup and Sync to Dropbox
# This script creates a backup using today's date, then deleted
# any backups made 3 days ago. If run every day it will ensure
# you have a week's worth of backups of your MySQL databases and
# zPanel web directories. 
#
# Uses whatever Dropbox account is running on the server.
#
# Written by Richard Ferreira for the backup of zPanel websites.
# Contact me - richard[at]beetle001.com
#----------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Before we get started, we should set some parameters. We'll need these for later.
# The webserver's datafiles:
WEBDIR="/var/zpanel/hostdata/"
# Where do we want the backup to go?  (SET THIS - IT'S A TEMP FOLDER)
BACKUP="/root/backup-temp"
# Where is our dropbox folder? (SET THIS TO YOUR ABSOLUTE BACKUP PATH)
DROPBOX="/root/Dropbox/Backups
# What do we want our date to look like?
NOW=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")
# We need to know the date 3 days ago to purge any backups that were made 3 days ago.
# This ensures we don't keep unnecessarily old backups.
# It doesn't matter if it skips one every now and then - we'll just have to check manually from time to time.
# If you want to keep more days backups, change the "3 days ago" to "x days ago"
DAYSAGO=$(date --date="3 days ago" +"%d-%m-%Y")
# What should our file backup look like?
WEBFILE="webdirs-full-$NOW.tar.gz"
# Our MySQL Login information and some paths (we'll use 'which' to make sure we get them):
SQLUSER="root"
# Don't forget to change the root password here!
SQLPASS="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
SQLHOST="localhost"
MYSQL="$(db-name)"
MYSQLDUMP="$(db-name)"
GZIP="$(.gz)"
#
# Let's just, for sanity's sake, make sure our temp backup folder exists.
mkdir $BACKUP
# DON'T EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Now let's start!
# Let's get the databases that we want to backup.
DBS="$($MYSQL -u $SQLUSER -h $SQLHOST -p$SQLPASS -Bse 'show databases')"
# Now let's dump them to .sql files and put them in our backup directory.
for db in $DBS
do
FILE=$BACKUP/mysql-$db.$NOW.gz
$MYSQLDUMP -u $SQLUSER -h $SQLHOST -p$SQLPASS $db | $GZIP -9 > $FILE
done
#
# Let's shove the whole webserver directory into a tarball and throw that in with the sql files:
tar -zcvf /root/backup/$WEBFILE $WEBDIR
# That's all done - we should put the backups on Copy by putting them into our Copy folder.
# First let's make a folder for today.
mkdir $DROPBOX/$NOW
# Copy our backups into it.
cp -R $BACKUP/* $DROPBOX/Asterix/$NOW
# We can delete the backup we made 3 days ago from Copy now.
rm -rf $DROPBOX/$DAYSAGO
# And clear out the temporary director for next time.
rm $BACKUP/*
# Job well done!
# Have a beer and relax!
```

Here is my problem:
When I try to run the script I get this error:
./backup.sh: 66: ./backup.sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

If anyone could help me with this would appreciate it a lot!

Comment: I think `DROPBOX="/root/Dropbox/Backups` should be `DROPBOX="/root/Dropbox/Backups"`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The line with

```
DROPBOX="/root/Dropbox/Backups
```

does not have a `"` at the end.

The `MYSQL`, `MYSQLDUMP` and `GZIP` variables refer to the programs used to execute various commands. So they should contain the path of those programs:

```
MYSQL="/usr/bin/mysql"
MYSQLDUMP="/usr/bin/mysqldump"
GZIP="/bin/gzip"
```

You can use the output of [`which <program name>`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/which.1.html) to see what to put there:

```
$ which mysql
/usr/bin/msql
$ which gzip
/bin/gzip
```

Comment: Ok I will see if that fixes. Also in the script I also did not know what to put in at: MYSQL="$()" MYSQLDUMP="$()" GZIP="$()"

So I just put my DB name in for the first two and .gz in the third one. Is that fine?

Comment: @Hamza for `MYSQL` in the brackets, use the output of `which mysql`, and `which mysqldump` for `MYSQLDUMP`. Similarly for `GZIP`. e.g.: `MYSQL=/usr/bin/mysql`.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue as seen below.

```
MY_VAR="123"#comments
```

then I put a space before # character, then solved.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash, if you want to escape a single quote, you can't just add a backslash to it...

Wrong code:

```shell
echo 'This is not how it\'s done'.
```

Correct code:

```shell
echo 'This is how it'\''s done'.
```

See [SC1003 – ShellCheck Wiki](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC1003)